# MVC 4 Bind dynamically created fields to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not entirely sure how to phrase the title of the question but here is my current situation.

I have a model that looks like this

```
public class ExpenseReport
{
    public ExpenseReport Report { get; set; }
    public List<ExpenseTransaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

[image: This is my create page right now]

I wanted to when the user clicks the add row add a new ExpenseTransaction to the form for them to fill in. Right now I currently have it properly creating the rows and when I submit I can see all the values when on the model when it comes into the create post. But I can't seem to get the newly created transaction to "bind" to the ExpenseTransaction model where I have all my validations on the fields.

Currently what I'm doing

```
$( '#AddRow' ).click( function ()
            {
                var rowCount = $( '#expense-transaction tr' ).length - 1;
                $.get( "@Url.Action("AddExpenseTransaction", "Expense")/" + rowCount, function ( data )
                {
                    $( "#expense-transaction tbody" ).append( data );
                } );
            } );

public ActionResult AddExpenseTransaction(int id)
{
    ExpenseTransactiontransaction = new ExpenseTransaction(id);
    return View(transaction);
}
```

On the click of addrow button I submit the row count to the action and return a partial view where I generate the new fields and add them back to the row. How do I make it so that the new created rows have validation on them from the model? 
I'm not exactly sure what key words to google to get this out since most of the searches come back as listing details and editing instead of creating.

Comment: You can try return the whole model (with the created field). Then use `ModelState.Clear` and resend the model that you've passed from the view back again.

Comment: At the moment it seems that about where I'm thinking of going.